# Is there any method to pass the multiple values or *args in the lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, arguments, multiple-variable-return

this is the simple lambda function which's take only single value as a parameter
a=lambda x: x**2
a(2)
output: 4

But i want to pass the multiple values in the lambda function like
a(2,3,4,5)
how it will work and what's the exact solution for this function?

Comment: `g = lambda *x: print(x)`?  Really though what exactly are you trying to do? You can also define `f = lambda a, b, c, d: ...` if you want to restrict it to 4 arguments.

Comment: There's nothing unusual. Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), please.